# Is there a way to resume file upload with Unity SDK using PutFileAsync?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is firebase allow to resume file upload for Unity SDK? As I seen from documentation previousSessionUri might be passed to the PutFileAsync method. But how I can retrieve this previousSessionUri?

I research documentation for other platforms and for retrieving this data they use UploadState for that. But in my case state.UploadSessionUri always return null. I try to use next code for solve this problem in different variations

```
bool isSessionRetrieved = false;
            Uri sessionUri = null;
            var progressState = new StorageProgress<UploadState>(state =>
            {
                
                sessionUri = state.UploadSessionUri;
                if (!isSessionRetrieved && sessionUri != null)
                {
                    isSessionRetrieved = true;
                    Debug.Log($"upload session: {sessionUri.AbsolutePath}");
                }
                // called periodically during the upload
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Progress: {0} of {1} bytes transferred.",
                    state.BytesTransferred, state.TotalByteCount));
            });

            uploadTask = fileRef.PutFileAsync(path, null, progressState, cToken, null)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError(task.Exception);
                }
                else
                {
                    StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string md5Hash = metadata.Md5Hash;
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("md5 hash = " + md5Hash);
                    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("prevSession");
                }
            });
```

but in all cases state.UploadSessionUri is null. Is something wrong in my code or this functionality does not implemented by Firebase SDK yet?